# generating Persist entity from database schema

Tags: haskell, persist

Is there a way to generate Persist entity directly from the database and eventualy save them into a file, so that I can't modify some of it instead of having to write everything manually.

I've read some post which says it's possible but I haven't found how to do it exactly.

Comment: You mean you want to introspect the database (table-names, col-names, data-types), figure out the appropriate Persistent types, and then write out the Persistent types to a file automatically?